# Putting category to markers android maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, markers

I want to categorize my markers like this http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_categories.htm, I dont have idea how to put type to my marker. Im stuck here. Here's my code. I tried this but it seems wrong

```
Marker malls = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(14.589740, 120.982111))
    .title("Welcome to the City of Maynila"))
    .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.blue));
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what problem you face ?

Comment: categorizing markers. for example categorizing it as malls, restaurants, gas station

Comment: means you want to show different-2 marker on different-2 category ?

Comment: example is like this @Golu [link]http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerhider/markerhider.htm

Comment: now what is the problem you facing ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way you have is using a Cluster Manager to add the items to the map.

you create a class that implements ClusterItem and create your own item.
You need to have a function to choose your icon type named setIconByData:

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {
    private final LatLng mPosition;
    private MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    private String data;
    private int iconReference;

public MyItem(double lat, double lng) {
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
}

public MyItem(MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    this.setMarkerOptions(markerOptions);
    mPosition = markerOptions.getPosition();
}

public MyItem(LatLng latLong) {
    mPosition = latLong;
}

@Override
public LatLng getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
}

public MarkerOptions getMarkerOptions() {
    return markerOptions;
}

public void setMarkerOptions(MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    this.markerOptions = markerOptions;
}

public int getIconReference() {
    return iconReference;
}

public void setIconReference(int iconReference) {
    this.iconReference = iconReference;
}

public void setIconByData(String data, MyItem myItem) {
    if(data.equals("museum"))
        myItem.setIconReference(iconMuseum);
    else
        myItem.setIconReference(iconGolf);
}
```

}

The you need a function in your activity or fragment class to organize the items.
This function needs to return a Collection of items:

```
private Collection<MyItem> organizeItems(LatLng latlong) {
   Collection<MyItem> res = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
   MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latlong);
   MyItem item = new MyItem(markerOptions);
   item.setIconByValencia("golf", item);
   res.add(item);   
   return res;
}
```

Then, when you want you clean the manager and add the new items:

```
mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(v.getContext(), map); //on create

//when you want to refresh the items:
mClusterManager.clearItems();
mClusterManager.addItems(addItems(BOUNDS, TicketTypeProduct.TO));
mClusterManager.cluster();
```

You can see here the detailing of using clusters and cluster manager:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering?hl=en-EN